# Node.js workers/background processes

Tags: node.js, delayed-job, resque

How can I create and use background jobs in node.js?

I've come across two libs (node-resque and node-worker) but would like to know if there's something more used.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I did some research on this and I would do it like this.

## Setup

### beanstalkd

1. Install [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/). Another message queue, **BUT** this one supports [DELAYED PUTS](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt). If you compile from source it is going to be a little harder because it depends on [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/)(like memcached). But then again, I don't think you have to compile it from source, because there are a lot of [binary packages](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/download.html) available. For example on Ubuntu you can install beanstalkd by issuing the command:

   `sudo apt-get install beanstalkd`

### node-beanstalk-client

2. Install a beanstalkd client library. The best one I found was [node-beanstalk-client](https://github.com/benlund/node-beanstalk-client). Because on the beanstalkd client library list this library isn't/wasn't mentioned(Then again I can add entries to the list, so I will add this one). The reasons I prefer this library over the others are:

   1. **Npm package**: I liked to use a npm package to install client library. The others did not have any.
   2. **Active development**: I prefer libraries which have later/more commits.

So to install it, after you have installed [npm](https://github.com/isaacs/npm)([the write way](https://gist.github.com/579814)) you would just issue the following command:

```
npm install beanstalk_client
```

## Code

### consumer.js

```
var client = require('beanstalk_client').Client;

client.connect('127.0.0.1:11300', function(err, conn) {
    var reserve = function() {
        conn.reserve(function(err, job_id, job_json) {
            console.log('got job: ' + job_id);
            console.log('got job data: ' + job_json);
            console.log('module name is ' + JSON.parse(job_json).data.name);
            conn.destroy(job_id, function(err) {
                console.log('destroyed job');
                reserve();
            });
        });
    }

    reserve();
});
```

First start the consumer:

```
node consumer.js
```

Next start `producer.js`. Five seconds(delay I specified) after you execute `producer.js`, `consumer.js` will process the message.

### producer.js

```
var client = require('beanstalk_client').Client;
client.connect('127.0.0.1:11300', function(err, conn) {
    var job_data = {"data": {"name": "node-beanstalk-client"}};
    var priority = 0;
    var delay = 5;
    var timeToRun = 1;
    conn.put(priority, delay, timeToRun, JSON.stringify(job_data), function(err, job_id) {
        console.log('put job: ' + job_id);
        process.exit();
    });
});
```

to start just issue:

```
node producer.js
```

Comment: Sorry Alfred. I really forgot to mark it as correct.! Thanks!

Comment: @Editor thanks :).
@Donald No problem :). Great this helped you out!

Answer (score 13):

I'm using [Kue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/kue).

> Kue is a feature rich priority job queue for node.js backed by redis. A key feature of Kue is its clean user-interface for viewing and managing queued, active, failed, and completed jobs.